# Register a local event monitor for keyboard events in an OSX command line application

Tags: objective-c, nsevent

I'm currently working on a command line application that has been mainly written in C and partly Objective C. It followed a pure procedural approach so far. For some reason I'm now trying to move this procedural approach to an architecture that bases on notifications and events. At the same time I'm introducing an object oriented design (but that's not the topic).  I worked a bit with the runloop and FSEvent API and hope that I found some good solution for some problems. My (hopefully) last problem now is the "user interaction". The app should listen for keystrokes of the user an react to it. 
So after some reading I cam to the NSEvent API and added the following line to my main.m:

```
  [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){NSLog(@"Key pressed"); return event;}];
```

It compiles fine but the events are not triggered. 
So I'm just asking myself whether such events are actually triggered for a command line application or whether I have to invoke some NSApplication class or other dependency in order to get this functionality.

I'm kind of familiar with C/C++ but I'm pretty new to the cocoa framework. So apologies, if my question is dumb.

Best Regards
Norbert

Comment: I'm guessing: NSEvent is part of AppKit and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` won't work without NSApplication.

Comment: Take a look at [Quartz Event Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreateForPSN)

Comment: I already had a a look at the Quartz Event Services like in this example: https://github.com/sdegutis/mjolnir/issues/9. However, they require superuser privs. Really? Superuser privs to catch a keyboard stroke? Bottom-line: I don't want my tool to require superuser privs.

Comment: Keystrokes are sent to the active app. A background app needs permission from the user to catch keystrokes.

Comment: I see your point. However, all the examples and guides that I can find about the Quartz Event Services in this area require the app to run as root. I don't care about the events that happen if my app is in the background. It's a command line tool that will only need to react to input as long as it has the focus.

Comment: Do you want input from the command line?

Comment: Yes. But the simple getch(); does not work as I had to start a runloop explicitly. By starting this runloop the execution of main.m stops and only event driven functions are executed. So I need some kind of framework that fires an event (best case to the runloop) and triggers a callback. The main reason ist that I want to give the user the option to cancel the execution of the tool without pressing Strg+C.